# Period map for products of K3 surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, k3-surfaces

If $X$ is a K3 surface, it carries a unique (up to scaling with $\mathbb{C}^*$) holomorphic 2-form $\sigma$, determined by the complex structure. Let $\Lambda=3U\oplus-2E_8$ be the K3-lattice. The period domain of a K3 surface is given by $$
\Omega=\{[\sigma]\in \mathbb{P}(\Lambda\otimes\mathbb{C})\colon \sigma\cdot\sigma=0, \sigma\cdot\overline{\sigma}>0\}.
$$
A marked K3 surface is a pair $(X,\phi)$, with $X$ K3 and where $\phi$ is an isometry $\phi:H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\to \Lambda$. Let $M_1$ be the set of equivalence classes of Marked K3 surfaces, and define the Period map $\tau:M_1\to \Omega$ by $\tau([X,\phi])=[\phi(\sigma_X)]$.

Now suppose $Y$ is another K3 surface, and consider the product of K3 surfaces $X\times Y$. I want to define the period map for this product. By Künneth's theorem, the natural map $$H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\oplus H^2(Y,\mathbb{Z})\to H^2(X\times Y,\mathbb{Z})$$ is an isomorphism, so this endows $H^2(X\times Y,\mathbb{Z})$ with the natural lattice structure, isomorphic to $\Lambda\oplus\Lambda$. Let $\phi:H^2(X\times Y,\mathbb{Z})\to \Lambda\oplus\Lambda$. The product $X\times Y$ carries two nowhere vanishing holomorphic 2-forms: $\sigma_1=\pi^*_X\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_2=\pi^*_Y\sigma_Y$. The new period domain would be $$
\Omega'=\{[(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)]\in\mathbb{P}((\Lambda\oplus\Lambda)\otimes\mathbb{C})\colon \sigma_1\cdot\sigma_1=0,\sigma_1\cdot\sigma_2=0,\sigma_2\cdot\sigma_2=0,\sigma_1\cdot\overline{\sigma_2}=0, \sigma_1\cdot\overline{\sigma_1}>0,\sigma_2\cdot\overline{\sigma_2}>0\},
$$
and I would like to define $\tau':M_1'\to \Omega'$ by $\tau'([X\times Y, \phi])=[(\phi(\sigma_1),\phi(\sigma_2)]$. However, this is not really well-defined. Is there a better way to define the period map for the product of K3 surfaces?

Edit: At first, I thought that $M_1'=M_1\times M_1, \Omega'=\Omega\times \Omega$ and $\tau'=\tau\times\tau$. However, this does not seem to work dimensionwise, so I am interested in any ideas!

Comment: Don’t the 2-forms vanish when restricted to the factor they weren’t pulled back from?

Comment: Off topic, but I think you were asking the other day whether the Kahler cone of a product was the product of Kahler cones when the second cohomology groups match up. For what it’s worth that is true: take a Kahler class on the product, write it as the sum of two pullback classes, and note that each of those must be Kahler because you can restrict the original class to one of the product factors and obtain the pullback class.

Comment: I had indeed found the same simple answer concerning the Kähler cones, but still thanks!

Comment: I am slightly confused by your comment that the 2-forms vanish. If $\sigma$ is nowhere vanishing on $X$, we have for each $p\in X$ that the map $\sigma_p:T_pX\to \mathbb{R}$ is not the zero map. Then, $\pi^*\sigma_{(p,q)}=\sigma_p\circ (d\pi)_{(p,q)}$ is not the zero map, since it does not pair to zero with $(v_p,0)\in T_pX\oplus T_qY$, where $v_p\in T_pX$ is non-zero, or am I misinterpreting the term nowhere vanishing, and should I interpret it as "Does not vanish for any non-zero tangent vector"?

Comment: Of course I should use 2-forms here and not 1-forms, but this should not change it

Comment: I think I mixed up “non-zero” and “non-degenerate”, sorry.

Comment: For 4folds, the interesting cohomology is H^4 instead of H^2. May be one should consider period map for H^4.